# Yay, we have runnable code snippets; Do I go and edit all my questions (causing them to rise to the top)?

Tags: discussion

[We now have runnable code snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1) (on programming related sites); so does that mean that we should:

- Edit all our questions/answers or,

Let them naturally evolve into this newer functionality?

The main concern is that now a whole bunch of older questions/answers *could* move into the 'interesting'/'active' questions pages.

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271506/should-we-edit-our-old-posts-to-include-stack-snippets

Answer (score 10):

No, do not do mass edits.

1. You will hit the daily limits for editing lots of posts in one day. This will stop you editing more and will raise an automatic moderator flag. We have enough flags to deal with without people adding more unnecessarily.
2. You will bump all your posts to the top of the home page. While one person doing this is probably not a problem (see point 1 above), everybody doing this would be. You would be displacing **new** questions that don't have answers that deserve their chance to get answers. All you are doing is "make work" on something that's fine as it is (see point 3 below).
3. What benefit will there be to your old questions/answers from doing this? The questions probably already have answers, the answers have been doing OK without snippets, they don't need any more help.

By all means convert the code to snippets when you are editing the post **for other reasons**, it won't hurt the post. However, mass editing by everyone is not the way to do this.

Comment: Much as I thought; as soon as I read the blog announcement, I immediately thought people will jump up and start editing old posts etc...